# How do I find the all domain names where name-server is authoritative?

Tags: domain-name-system, domains, dig, nslookup, nameserver

is possibles query a name server and have the list of domains for which he is authoritative?

Comment: sounds like a serious security issue, so I hope there isn't... :)

Comment: Hi Roe, an idea on how to do this without a DNS query?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to do this within the DNS protocols.

Some sites (of varying repute) have built up their own databases where they've simply trawled the net and recorded which domains are known to be on which name servers.

However by definition such a database can never be complete, because when a new domain is created they have to somehow get wind of its existence before it can be queried.